# How to use Unicode string for primary key in SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework, unicode, indexing, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble inserting a record with a primary key that only varies by some special Unicode characters.

For example, if I have a record already in the database with a primary key of `"test"` and I try to insert another record that has a primary key of `"test + '\u13A4' + '\u13B4' + '\u13B9'"` I get a duplicate key error. I am using EF 5 with SQL Server 2012.

The primary key is defined as an `nvarchar` and the collation is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. It can do a look-up on the primary key just fine if there are special Unicode characters in there but if it just varies by the Unicode special characters (as in the example above) I get the duplicate key error on inserts. How do you get around this issue?

Comment: try using collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC, as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL_Latin1_CP1 collation does not cater for all Unicode codepoints.

```
select N'test' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
union
select N'test' + nchar(5028) + nchar(5044) + nchar(5049)
-- result: 1 row
```

Use the newer ones for SQL Server 2008 onwards, e.g.

```
select N'test' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
union
select N'test' + nchar(5028) + nchar(5044) + nchar(5049)
-- result: 2 rows
```

The unicode characters you are using fall within the 16-bit character range, so supplementary characters don't come into play yet.

Answer (score 0):

This must be related to how you are concatenating the string. The following works for me:

```
    CREATE TABLE #UnicodeTest (
      UnicodePK NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS PRIMARY KEY 
    )

    INSERT #UnicodeTest
            ( UnicodePK )
    VALUES  ( N'test'
              )

    INSERT #UnicodeTest
            ( UnicodePK )
    VALUES  ( N'test\u13A4\u13B4\u13B9'
              )

    INSERT #UnicodeTest
            ( UnicodePK )
    VALUES  ( N'test + \u13A4 + \u13B4 + \u13B9'
              )

    INSERT #UnicodeTest
            ( UnicodePK )
    VALUES  ( N'test + ''\u13A4'' + ''\u13B4'' + ''\u13B9'''
              )


    SELECT * FROM #UnicodeTest

    DROP TABLE #UnicodeTest
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The string in my question was in C# code and that is how you escape special unicode characters. Your test in is just inserting a string with the escape sequence and not the actual unicode characters. For TSQL you need to use nchar with the decimal value. If you use N'test' + nchar(5028) + nchar(5044) + nchar(5049) it will fail.